# Webpack not finding SCSS ampersand class

Tags: webpack, sass, webpacker

I am migrating some SCSS code over that was written for our team to our rails app with webpacker (which runs webpack) and am running into some problems. It is probably quite easy but I am a bit unfamiliar with SCSS and webpack in general, so it has been causing some headaches.

I have an application.css file that looks like this:

```
@import "./base/_fonts.scss";
@import "./base/_typography.scss";
@import "./base/_transition.scss";
@import "./base/_grid.scss";
@import "./base/_space.scss";
@import "./base/_link.scss";
...
```

Inside "_transition.scss" there is:

```
// Timing
.timing {
  &-1 {
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }

  &-2 {
    transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
  }

  &-3 {
    transition-timing-function: var(--bezier-1);
  }
}
```

And yet when webpack compiles this section in "_link.scss" fails:

```
// Links
.link {
  @apply no-underline
        font-medium
        inline-block
        timing-1 duration-1 property-all;
```

With the error:

```
ERROR in ./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--3-2!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(3:3) `@apply` cannot be used with `.timing-1` because `.timing-1` either cannot be found, or its actual definition includes a pseudo-selector like :hover, :active, etc. If you're sure that `.timing-1` exists, make sure that any `@import` statements are being properly processed *before* Tailwind CSS sees your CSS, as `@apply` can only be used for classes in the same CSS tree.
I am guessing that the scss isn't compiled right because I am using postcss-loader instead of sass-loader or something, but I am at the edge of my knowledge with this stuff and wouldn't know how to change that even if that were the case.
```

Here is my "postcss.config.js" file:

```
const tailwindcss = require('tailwindcss')

module.exports = {
  parser: require('postcss-scss'),

  plugins: [
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('postcss-strip-inline-comments'),
    require('tailwindcss')('./app/javascript/stylesheets/tailwind.js'),
    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
    require('postcss-nested'),
    require('postcss-preset-env')({
      autoprefixer: {
        flexbox: 'no-2009'
      },
      stage: 3
    }),
    require('autoprefixer')
  ]
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This had to do with my entry css file being named "css" and not "scss", which caused the sass loader to give this strange error.